# Why the full wordpress site is down because of one syntax error

Tags: wordpress, php-parse-error

I was using a *List category posts* plugin and while editing for custom need a one file of this plugin - i have got an error (it was because of wrong usage of backslashes to escape special characters within quotes):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/i/ingeniumru/visionlabs/public_html/wp-content/plugins/list-category-posts/include/lcp-catlistdisplayer.php on line 487
```

And this error on all pages through the site (admin panel also), which even don't use the plugin functionality.

I ask the community to explain such a correlation between Wordpress php-files.

Comment: Сant understand the reasons people voting down and do not write any comments. Is description unclear? - i do not ask any certain instructions.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress load all active plugin and the active theme (just to know if he should use it or not).

If you have a plugin that make your website down, including backend, you can just go to your FTP (zip it : to have a backup) and remove the plugin folder. Then your site will be ok again.

Comment: The key words for me as a dummy - **"load all active plugins"**. Thank you. In my case there was no ftp-access (team lead had changed the password) for that moment (midnight) and the plugin's file was edited through the File Manager plugin. So, when backend was broken - File Manager editing functions began unavailable too. Now I understand that  editing even small detail with File Manager should be taken with carefulness.